# java depth first search

Tags: java, depth-first-search

This is my implementation for the reachable() of a graph using depth first search. It looks for a  possible path from vertex 1 (v1) to another vertex (v2)
I got some results correctly and some are wrong. I have tried as many ways as I can to debug, but I couldn'd figure out where is wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
public boolean isReachable(V v1, V v2) {
            Stack<V> path = new Stack<V>();
            return isReachableHelper(v1, v2, path);
        }

}

public boolean isReachableHelper(V v1, V v2, Stack<V> path){
        path.push(v1);
        v1.setVisited(true); //set the vertex as being visited

        if (v1.vertex().equals(v2.vertex())){ //check whether vertex' values are equal
            return true;
        }

            //loop through all vertex that are neighbors of v1
        for (V neighbor : super.neighbors(v1)){ 
            if (!neighbor.visited ){ //if the neighbor is not visited before
                return isReachableHelper(neighbor, v2, path); //recursive call
            }
        }

        path.pop(); //no path was found
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem: In your `for` loop, you only ever expand the first non-visited neighbor node and then immediately return the value of that recursive call. I.e., if no path can be found via the first neighbor of `v1`, you just 'give up' without looking at the other neighbors.

Instead, you have to try *all* neighbor nodes until you find one for which the recursive call returns `true`. In this case, you have found a path and you can return `true`; otherwise, your method correctly pops the last node from the path and returns `false` (backtracking).

```
for (V neighbor : super.neighbors(v1)){ 
    if (!neighbor.visited ){ //if the neighbor is not visited before
        if (isReachableHelper(neighbor, v2, path)) { //recursive call
            return true; // we found a path!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i was *just* writing up the same thing.

Comment: @Mikeb Sorry about that! ^^; There really should be an indicator for answers-in-progress...

Comment: nah, I like your explanation better than where I was going anyway.

Comment: perfect explanation. Thank you